# Using TPTP to profile an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, profiling, eclipse-tptp

I’m currently trying to profile an Eclipse Plugin using the TPTP tools.  However, I have run into issues when trying to profile an plugin.  I can profile a Java application fine, however when I try to profile an plugin, the runtime workbench fails to load and the profiling terminates after a few seconds.

I’m at a lost to what I’m doing wrong; I’m using Eclipse 3.4.0 and have the following TPTP features installed.  Is there something I’m missing?

```
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.analysis (4.4.101.v200901090956-7F7_EC6_kE77g7A7g7A77) "TPTP Analysis"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.analysis.codereview.java (4.4.201.v200901090956-7877_98s733K353K3533) "Java Code Review Plug-in"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.analysis.engine (4.3.300.v200901090956-784CE8s733J464H3533) "TPTP Analysis Engine"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.core (4.5.2.v200901090956-8Z8DF8kELRXmqCoI2oujyq) "TPTP Platform"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.core.doc.user (4.3.301.v200901090956-7B6EC49oA55U697O5855) "TPTP Platform Project Documentation"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.doc.user (4.3.301.v200901090956-7B77EC58_JLz0Y3HuPJBbBLAT9B6) "TPTP Platform Project Documentation"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.instrumentation.ui (4.2.200.v200901090956-78778a8s733K353K3533) "TPTP Instrumentation UI Core"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.integration.pde (4.4.100.v200901090956-438Y7w311_121_1211) "TPTP Platform Integration PDE"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.jvmti (4.3.201.v200901090956-7877CF8s733K364J3533) "TPTP JVMTI Profiler Client"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.la.core (4.3.200.v200812160100-42_77w311923271211) "Log Analysis Core backward compatibility"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.lta (4.3.300.v200901090956-783Dp8s733J464H3533) "TPTP Log and Trace Analyzer"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.probekit (4.3.301.v200901090956-7F5ELS_kE77g7A9g7A77) "TPTP ProbeKit"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.probekit.doc.user (4.3.300.v200901090956-41Ag7w311_121_1211) "Probekit User Documentation"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.report (4.2.300.v200901090956-7B5EAU9oA55V585V5855) "TPTP Charting Service"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.samples (4.3.300.v200901090956-7B4EDc9oA55V586R5855) "TPTP Platform Samples"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.statistical.ui (4.1.500.v200901090956-783CE8s733J365H3533) "TPTP Statistical UI"
org.eclipse.tptp.platform.trace (4.3.301.v200901090956-7J7EEFFAgI99r9EAh9D99) "TPTP Platform Trace"
org.eclipse.tptp.trace (4.2.201.v200901090956-781EDf8s733K353K3KCE) "TPTP Trace"
org.eclipse.tptp.trace.arm (4.2.200.v200901090956-782CE8s733K353K3KCE) "TPTP ARM Monitoring "
org.eclipse.tptp.trace.arm.ui (4.3.200.v200901090956-785Ag8s733K353K3KCE) "Instrument ARM UI"
org.eclipse.tptp.trace.jvmti (4.2.201.v200901090956-43_87w311_12211211) "TPTP Trace JVMTI Client"
```

Comment: Just a comment, I have had problems with TPTP whenever I use it and I have read that other people find it very problematic as well. I recommend just to avoid it if you can.

Comment: We also could not do anything with TPTP. Maybe you will find something useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762/please-recommend-a-java-profiler

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, I'm looking at alternatives at the moment.  Its a shame really, TPTP seemed to have quite a bit of potential.